# How is this inequality answer correct?

Tags: inequality

The question is :- "How many liters of water will have to be added to 1125
 liters of the 
45
%
 solution of acid so that the resulting mixture will contain more than
25
%
 but less than 
30
%
 acid content ?"
The answer everywhere is given as:- (Given in the picture)
[image: Answer]

Why is 25% of (1125 + x) < 45% of 1125?
We know the resulting mixture will contain more than 25% acid content, so all we can say is 25% of 1125 + x > 25% acid.
Please explain. Thank You. I know there is this same question, but I want to understand this, not get the answer. Thank You.

Comment: I suppose we're not working with a weak acid.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of a 'pure acid' is $45\%$ of $1125\,ltr$, that is $V_a = 0.45\cdot 1125\,l$.

Of course, the same amount of acid will be in the weaker solution after adding $x$ liters of water, so the final concentration is
$$\frac {V_a} {1125\,l+x}$$
and we need it to be between $25$ and $30$ percent:
$$0.25 < \frac {0.45\cdot 1125\,l} {1125\,l+x} < 0.30$$
Multiply all sides by the denominator:
$$0.25\cdot(1125\,l+x) < 0.45\cdot 1125\,l < 0.30\cdot(1125\,l+x)$$
and the left-hand side inequality is the one you asked about.

Hopefully it is clear now, why it should hold for $x$ to satisfy the problem requirements.

**UPDATE**

Put it another way, with more words and less maths:

$45\%$ of $1125$ is the volume of 'pure acid', so if we need a new solution stronger than $25\%$, then acid volume must be greater than $25\%$ of the new solution volume:
$$V_a > 25\%\ (1125\,l +x)$$
Substitute $45\%\ 1125\,l$ for $V_a$ and swap sides, and you get
$$25\%\ (1125\,l +x) < 45\%\ 1125\,l$$

Comment: Thank You sir/mam, I understood the first one. But in the second one, I do not get the statement, "Then acid volume must be greater than 25% of new solution volume". How can we say that?

Comment: @RamKeswani That is the requirement in your problem statement: _"How many liters of water will have to be added (....) so that the resulting mixture **will contain more than 25 %** (...) **acid** content ?"_

Comment: How is 25% (1125 + x) < 40% 1125? I mean in what context? Volume or acid content. Thank You,